# ValueError: Tensorflow2 wrong output dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow, sequential

Im working with the Iris dataset using tensorflow2

after fitting my model I get this error message

```
ValueError: A target array with shape (135, 4, 8) was passed for an output of shape (None, 3) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.
```

I'm importing / splitting / one hot encoding the model with:

```
iris_data = datasets.load_iris()    
def read_in_and_split_data(iris_data):
        return model_selection.train_test_split(iris_data["data"], iris_data["data"], test_size=0.1)
train_data, test_data, train_targets, test_targets = read_in_and_split_data(iris_data)
```

train_data shape is (135, 4)

train_target shape is (135, 4)

```
train_targets = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(np.array(train_targets))
test_targets = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(np.array(test_targets))
```

loss = "categorical_crossentropy"

```
def get_model(input_shape):
   model = Sequential([
       Dense(64, activation = "relu", kernel_initializer='he_uniform', bias_initializer='ones', input_shape=input_shape),
       Dense(128, activation = "relu"),
       Dense(128, activation = "relu"),
       Dense(128, activation = "relu"),
       Dense(128, activation = "relu"),
       Dense(64, activation = "relu"),
       Dense(64, activation = "relu"),
       Dense(64, activation = "relu"),
       Dense(64, activation = "relu"),
       Dense(3, activation = "softmax"),
       ])
    return model
model = get_model(train_data[0].shape)
def train_model(model, train_data, train_targets, epochs):
    return model.fit(train_data, train_targets, epochs)
history = train_model(model, train_data, train_targets, epochs=800)
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: You don't have the same number of samples in your `train_data` and `train_target`?

Comment: sorry i mixed up test_data and train_targets when i made the question. thank you for noting that!

Comment: edited the question and added how I'm importing the model. Would you have any recommendation on this? thank you!

Comment: Try changing your last layer to `Dense(4, activation = "softmax")`. Howevever, your error says your `train_target` dataset has a different shape from what you said.

Comment: actually the iris dataset shouldnt have a target dimension of (135, 4). I have set the output layer to 3 units because of the 3 classes in the dataset. I will revise how i am loading the set now.

Comment: got it. in def read_in_and_split_data(iris_data): instead of loading "data" and "target" i just loaded "data" two times... i now loaded with "target" and all works fine.
thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

solved it

in def read_in_and_split_data(iris_data): i was reading loading "data" two times instead of loading "data" and then "targets"

below is the correct code:

```
def read_in_and_split_data(iris_data):
        return model_selection.train_test_split(iris_data["data"], iris_data["target"], test_size=0.1)
```